# How to toggle a line block comment in KDevelop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kdevelop

Here is a selection:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        return 5;
    else
        return 7;

    return 0;
}
```

After "toggle comment", I'd like to see this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    if (argc > 1)
//        return 5;
//    else
        return 7;

    return 0;
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + D to comment

Ctrl + Shift + D to uncomment.

You can also configure the shortcuts by clicking on menu entry "Settings"->"Configure Shortcuts".

Comment: It doesn't comment entire lines.

Comment: it works perfectly for me, if you are on linux can you try downloading the app image and see if the issue persists? [link of appimage](https://www.kdevelop.org/download). Edit: I just noticed that you weren't selecting the entire lines, as FLHerne said that behaviour doesn't exist (afaik)

Comment: Then select the code you do want to perform the action on first. (The behaviour you're looking for doesn't exist, afaik).

Comment: @FLHerne, I've noticed that it doesn't exist. That's why I asked.